# Slick Slider not initializing with API json

Tags: json, api, slick.js

Trying to incorporate slick slider with an API but for some reason it won't work.

Not sure if I'm doing something wrong.

html

```
<div class="row">
  <div id="test">
    <div class="card top">Hello! My name is<div class="name">Izzy</div><div class="location">Alamo, CA</div><div class="sex-age">Female, adult</div></div>

    <div class="card top">Hello! My name is<div class="name">Izzy</div><div class="location">Alamo, CA</div><div class="sex-age">Female, adult</div></div>

    <div class="card top">Hello! My name is<div class="name">Izzy</div><div class="location">Alamo, CA</div><div class="sex-age">Female, adult</div></div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="row">
  <div id="cats">
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see the first slider "#test" does work with the same html markup as the one in the bottom named "#cats"

For some reason the slider #cats won't initialize though. Does it have to do with me using append() to the div with id "cats"?

js

```
    $(document).ready( function() {

  $.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/187677", function(data){

    $.each(data.pets, function() {

      var name = this["pet_name"];
      var sex = this["sex"];
      var age = this["age"];
      var state = this["addr_state_code"];
      var image = this ["large_results_photo_url"];
      var city = this ["addr_city"];

      if ( sex = "m") {
        sex = "Male";
      }
      if ( sex = "f") {
        sex = "Female";
      }

      $("#cats").append(
          "<div class='card top'>" +
            "Hello! My name is"+
            "<div class='name'>" + name + "</div>" +
            "<div class='location'>" + city + ", " +state + "</div>" +
            "<div class='sex-age'>" + sex + ", " + age + "</div>" +
          "</div>"
      );


    });  
  });

  $('#cats').slick();
  $('#test').slick();

});
```

THank you in advanced!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to initialize the `slick` plugin for the `#cats` after you have inserted the relevant slides in the DOM

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

      $.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/187677", function(data) {

        $.each(data.pets, function() {

          var name = this["pet_name"];
          var sex = this["sex"];
          var age = this["age"];
          var state = this["addr_state_code"];
          var image = this["large_results_photo_url"];
          var city = this["addr_city"];

          if (sex = "m") {
            sex = "Male";
          }
          if (sex = "f") {
            sex = "Female";
          }

          $("#cats").append(
            "<div class='card top'>" +
            "Hello! My name is" +
            "<div class='name'>" + name + "</div>" +
            "<div class='location'>" + city + ", " + state + "</div>" +
            "<div class='sex-age'>" + sex + ", " + age + "</div>" +
            "</div>"
          );
        });
        $('#cats').slick();
      });

      $('#test').slick();
});
```

---

Alternatively you can initialize the plugin earlier, and use the `.slice('slickAdd', 'html node here')` method

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').slick();
    $('#cats').slick();
    $.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/187677", function(data) {

        $.each(data.pets, function() {

          var name = this["pet_name"];
          var sex = this["sex"];
          var age = this["age"];
          var state = this["addr_state_code"];
          var image = this["large_results_photo_url"];
          var city = this["addr_city"];

          if (sex = "m") {
            sex = "Male";
          }
          if (sex = "f") {
            sex = "Female";
          }

          $("#cats").slick('slickAdd', 
            "<div class='card top'>" +
            "Hello! My name is" +
            "<div class='name'>" + name + "</div>" +
            "<div class='location'>" + city + ", " + state + "</div>" +
            "<div class='sex-age'>" + sex + ", " + age + "</div>" +
            "</div>"
          );
        });
      });
 });
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That fixed it.

Comment: @KenRyan added an alternative version as well

Comment: After Many years, still a life savior