# Slick slider throws error with slickAdd

Tags: jquery, json, slick.js

I'm building a slider with data taken from JSON, i've found this answer [Slick Slider not initializing with API json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43402747/slick-slider-not-initializing-with-api-json) but I don't know why it's not working for me.

```
// JSON vars
var jsonURL = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/cy34x'; // original

// IE9 compatibility
$.support.cors = true;

// getJSON function to display content inside DIV element

$('.slick-carousel-home').slick();

$.getJSON(jsonURL, function(data) {

    data.info.forEach( function( item ){
        //console.log(item)
        var slideName = Object.keys( item )[0];
        var slideObj = item[ slideName ]

        var slideTitle = slideObj[0].title;
        var slideSubTitle = slideObj[1].subtitle;
        var slideSource = slideObj[2].image;

        $('.slick-carousel-home').slick('slickAdd', '<article><img src=' + slideSource + ' ></article>');
    });


});
```

When I try to add the slides to the slider the consolle throws an error "Cannot read property 'add' of null", any suggestions? thx